# onCreateOptionsMenu not called in fragment when using fragment transaction. Will appear when fragment is included in XML

Tags: java, android, fragment, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have a menu created that I am trying to display in my Fragment. Everything works well if the fragment is included in the activities xml layout file. But if I try to add the fragment to the frameLayout via fragment transaction without changing any other implementation the menu will not appear.

Activity

```
Fragment frag = Fragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, frag)
            .commit();

Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater 
inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
   >

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".60"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <!--<fragment-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/frag"-->
    <!--android:name="name"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
    <!--</fragment>-->

 </FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/controls_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        android:name="ControlsFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/softGray"
 android:clickable="true"
 android:focusable="true"
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsedText"
            app:contentScrim="@color/softGray"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="@string/action_groups">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.5"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_skyscraper" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/main_groups_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Menu Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/string"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
   />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_edit_black_alpha_24dp"
    android:title="@string/string"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
   />

  <item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/string"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
  </menu>
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `setSupportActionBar` before your FragmentTransaction?

Comment: I have tried that, and it didn't seem to matter.